# Can I adjust the size of the scrollback buffer of a certain terminal window?

Tags: terminal, memory

I want to adjust the size of the scrollback buffer of a certain terminal that is already open and running a command (that produces a lot of output). Currently the size of the buffer is set to be limited only by the size of the memory but it slows down my whole system when the lines can be counted in the millions.

However, the only way I have found to do this is to open the inspector and then double click the profile and finally change the profile's setting for the size of the scrollback buffer. The problem with this is that it affects all other terminals that use the profile.

In older versions of OS X (I am on High Sierra), IIRC, you could adjust this setting per window in the inspector. Has this setting moved somewhere else or has it disappeared completely?